# If $u:[0,\infty)\times\mathcal V\to\mathbb R^d$ is divergence-free, then $\partial u/\partial t$ is divergence-free too

Tags: sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics, weak-derivatives, divergence-operator

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\mathcal V\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open
- $u:[0,\infty)\times\mathcal V\to\mathbb R^d$ with

  - $u(\;\cdot\;,x)\in C^1(\mathbb R_{\ge 0},\mathbb R^d)$ for all $x\in\mathcal V$
  - $u(t,\;\cdot\;)\in H_0^1(\mathcal V,\mathbb R^d)$ for all $t\ge 0$

Suppose that $$\nabla\cdot u:=\sum_{i=1}^d\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_i}=0\;.\tag 1$$ I want to show that $$\nabla\cdot\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0\;.\tag 2$$

If $u(t,\;\cdot\;)\in C^1(\mathcal V,\mathbb R^d)$ for all $t\ge 0$, then $(1)$ is obvious by *Schwarz' theorem*. How can we show it in general?

Comment: Your assumptions do not even allow do write down $\nabla (\partial u/\partial t)$.

Comment: @gerw Why not? Which assumptions do we need?

Comment: Why? How do you define it?

Comment: @gerw If $v\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal V,\mathbb R^d)$ is weakly differentiable, then $w\in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathcal V)$ is the weak divergence of $v$ iff $$\langle\phi,w\rangle_{L^2(\mathcal V)}=-\langle v,\nabla\phi\rangle_{L^2(\mathcal V,\mathbb R^d)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Omega)\;.$$ In that case, we write $w=\nabla\cdot v$. But I guess, I got your point. We would need that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(t,\;\cdot\;)\in H_0^1(\mathcal V,\mathbb R^d)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge 0\;,$$ but I'm not sure if we can expect that with the given assumptions.

Comment: @gerw Do you know which assumptions we need?

Comment: If $u$ belongs to $H^1(0,T; H_0^1(V,\mathbb R^d))$ it should work. I am not sure whether weaker assumptions are possible.

Comment: @gerw Do you know how we can prove the statement (with your assumption)?

Comment: Because $\nabla \cdot (\partial u/\partial t) = \partial(\nabla \cdot u)/\partial t= \partial0/\partial t = 0$.